# How to make crescent rolls soft and fluffy?

Tags: baking, rolls

I have tried a couple of times to make my crescent rolls light, soft, and fluffy, but I have not managed to achieve that yet. They turn out a bit too heavy. My guess is that the dough is too sticky, so when I knead it I add more flour than is needed. Any help here? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice! Could you share the recipe (and brand, if using premade rolls)? It will be hard for others to assist you without that information.

Answer (score 2):

First thought with any roll/croissant/ etc is the dough needs to be made with COLD ingredients.

This allows layers to be formed and this is what creates the magic.

If ingredients, especially butter, are not cold then they make a gloppy thick dough. Cold ingredients make nice, clean layers that lead to lighter finished products.

Comment: With something like croissants, I believe the more layers you can get while maintaining that butter distribution and the integrity of each layer will result in lighter, flakier, softer as well.  It is essential the butter stay cold to form those layers that result in the lightness from the gases and the structure from the fat/flour.   It is something I fail at myself so enjoy when I find them fresh and correct.